# Create an Excel document directly into a SharePoint folder using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint

I want to create a new Excel document in SharePoint using PowerShell (directly without upload). Is this possible ?
I'm able to create an Excel document on disk and upload it to SharePoint using PowerShell, but I can't manage to create it directly into a SharePoint folder.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: you could use importExcel from david finke to start with. https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel   What have you tried so far?

Comment: Creating an Excel document on disk and uploading to SharePoint isn't a problem. I want to create a new Excel document directly in a SharePoint folder.

Comment: Have you done any research on this subject? With one simple google search I found the following documentation on the REST API of SP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest  it contains multiple examples including a "how to create a file in a specific folder"

Comment: I've tried multiple searches on this subject, but didn't found an applicable solution. I didn't find this one, so thanks I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just access the directory via UNC path and create the file that way.

Bear in mind you may have issues with WebDAV, as I did. See my question (and the comments under it - I essentially just run explorer to open the path and thereafter I could use the UNC path easily).

It’s over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36455875/1868534)

Comment: Thanks a million !

Comment: @JohnDoe you’re welcome! Glad it helped - this drove me to distraction when developing the script in question! Saving someone else any of that pain can only be a good thing!